# angularjs dependency injection $scope not working

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS DI concept, Can anyone tell me why below code not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])

    var myController = myApp.controller('MyController', function(a){
        a.name = 'william'
        console.log(a.name)
    })

    myController.$inject = ['$scope']

    </script>
```

Iam getting an error as:  `https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a`

In above code, in place of 'a', if replaced with '$scope', it definitely works. As far as I understand, angular should inject $scope into 'a' parameter, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$inject` must be defined on the controller, not on the module:

```
var ctrl = function(a) { ... };
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
myApp.controller('MyController', ctrl);
```

But I strongy suggest you

- use $scope for your variable rather than `a`
- let [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) transform the code to minifiable code automatically.

Comment: I updated my code, still not injecting..whats the problem? BTW, when should I use ng-annotate?

Comment: Sorry. Mistake on my side. See the edited answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/DKUS15Qn4XwvjBmXfIus?p=preview

Comment: In your code, you have created some function and then at line 7, you have declared as myController.$inject = ['$scope'] , but why does it not give an error at this line ? The reason i asked because $inject belongs to  angularjs, right? myController is just a function, so how does a normal function can call $inject directly?

Comment: A function is also an object in JavaScript, and can thus have arbitrary, dynamically assigned attributes, like $inject.

Comment: okay fine. But I do not understand one thing, Why does my code not working? I mean why injecting getting failed in my case..whats the differnce between your code and mine? you first created function outside and then used it inside .controller, right?  Could you please explain briefly?

Comment: You're setting $inject on the module. You need to set it on the controller function. A module is a set of controllers, directives, filters, etc. All don't require the same injected services. So setting $inject on the module makes no sense. Each controller, service, directive, is injected with something different from the others. So all need their own $inject.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`$inject` should be on controller function:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])

    myApp.controller('MyController', function myController(a){
        a.name = 'william'
        console.log(a.name)
    })

    myController.$inject = ['$scope']
```